# Hiding common component on Not Found Page in React-Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In my react app, there is a common header which is outside of my Routes and other components are loaded based on routing.

```
      <React.Fragment>
            <Header />
            <div className="container dflex">
              <Switch>
                <Route path="/money-transfer" component={MoneyTransfer} />
                <Redirect from="/" to="/money-transfer" exact />
                <Route path="/dmt" exact component={MyDmt} />
                <Route component={NoFound} />
              </Switch>
          </div>
      </React.Fragment>
```

I want to also hide my header when NoFound Page is rendered.
What can be the best possible solution for this ?

Answer (score 2):

You could `Redirect` to a particular route when no route is matched and then check for that route in `Header` to hide that component.

```
 <Switch>
    <Route path="/money-transfer" component={MoneyTransfer} />
    <Redirect from="/" to="/money-transfer" exact />
    <Route path="/dmt" exact component={MyDmt} />
    <Route component={NoFound} />
 </Switch>

function NoFound() {
  return <Redirect to="/notfound" />;
}
```

// Header.js

```
const Header = props => {
  const { location } = props;

  if (location.pathname.match(/notfound/)) {
    return <NotFoundRoute />;
  }
  return <h3>I am the Header</h3>;
};

export default withRouter(Header);
```

// NotFoundRoute.js

```
function NotFoundRoute() {
  return <div>No Route Found</div>;
}
```

Working code sample [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-basic-lyzcx)

Hope that helps!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
  <React.Fragment>
                 let HideHeader = NoFound ? null : <Header />
                 {HideHeader}
                <div className="container dflex">
                  <Switch>
                    <Route path="/money-transfer" component={MoneyTransfer} />
                    <Redirect from="/" to="/money-transfer" exact />
                    <Route path="/dmt" exact component={MyDmt} />
                    <Route component={NoFound} />
                  </Switch>
              </div>
          </React.Fragment>
```